# How to set texts in android for Tablelayouts?

Tags: java, android, xml, tablelayout, settext

I'm trying to set some values to text views in a table layout, but I can't test it on my phone due to self-closing the app.

My XML file is defined here:

```
 <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableAfc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">
   <TableRow
       android:id="@+id/rowAf1"
   >
     <TextView
         android:text="Litera"
         android:singleLine="true"
        android:id="@+id/tAf1"
        android:padding="5dip" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Pozitie initiala"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:id="@+id/tAf2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dip" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Pozitie mediana"
        android:id="@+id/tAf3"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dip" />
     <TextView
        android:text="Pozitie finala"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:id="@+id/tAf4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dip" />
    </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
```

My java code...

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
       super.onCreate(icicle);
       setContentView(R.layout.cons_africate);
       TextView t1= (TextView) super.findViewById(R.id.tAf1);
       t1.setText(1);
   }
```

If I don't try to change the text in the java code, it works, but with those two lines it crashes...

Comment: For future reference, you may want to post the stack trace or exception that you are experiencing when you run the code and it crashes

Answer (score 2):

`t1.setText(1);` does not work because `setText()` only accept **CharSquence** type. So use `t1.setText("1");`

Comment: There is not only a `setText(Charsequence)` method. There is a `setText(int)` method as well but the int parameter should be a string resource id.

Comment: If you look at R.java where all the static attributes with layout and strings.xml which return as a Char sequence, you are talking about setText(int resId). But the 'resId' must be as referenced in strings.xml which return char sequence.

Answer (score -2):

use inverted comas in settext i.e "1"

Comment: this is not an answer